# How to pass value from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pass value from javascript to html but I can't do it, I used return in js function but probably not correctly

```js
function add() {
  var a3 = document.getElementById('a').value;
  return a3;
}
var a5 = add();
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = a5;
```

```html
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>

  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <p id="greeting">Greetings</p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function call is happening way before the click event (on page load), instead of returning the value from function you can update the element's content inside the function itself.

Also, I will suggest you use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to set the content if it is simple string (not *htmlString*).

You can try the following way:

```js
function add() {
  var a3 = document.getElementById('a').value;
  document.getElementById("greeting").textContent += " " + a3;    
}
```

```html
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>

  <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <p id="greeting">Greetings</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are calling `add()` from html button onClick, you can need to update DOM from add function itself with `innerText`

```js
function add() {
  var a3 = document.getElementById('a').value;
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerText = a3;
}
```

```html
a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>

<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<p id="greeting">Greetings</p>
```